# How can I determine which photos in Picasa are linked from Blogger blog?

Tags: blogger, picasa-web-albums

My wife has used the standard Blogger photo upload functionality in her blog, so all the photos ended up on Picasa. Today she ran out of space. We noticed however, that in Picassa some of the pictures are duplicated (triplicated, etc.) How can I figure out which ones? We use Picasa only for Blogger, so an automated script to detect all the photos that are unused in Blogger would be ideal.

Even checking the photos one-by-one is tricky - the link in Blogger is completely different from the link in Picasa. How can we determine manually which ones match?

Comment: Could you post the URL to the blog?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal, the url is buczekmruczek.blogspot.com

Comment: Which Picasa album do the duplicated photos end up in? Are both the original and the duplicates in the Blogger album, or are they in separate albums?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal, they end up in the same blogger album, often next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pictures smaller than 2048 x 2048 pixels are ignored and they don't count as used space, only bigger pictures. So you might worry to clear only those pictures that are bigger than that.

Source: [Free storage - Picasa and Picasa web albums help](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1224181)

Answer (score 3):

The images in the folder(s) with the blog's name are the ones used.

The second part of the url contains the actual key to the image:

e.g.
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tc0JaPm2Luo/VJqZUl8q-UI/AAAAAAAA5k8/fVCSrRSl7t4/s1600/Navy-F-18-Hornet-Christmas-lights.jpg

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tc0JaPm2Luo/VJqZUl8q-UI/AAAAAAAA5lA/YMyATHLE0Fs/s1600/Navy-F-18-Hornet-Christmas-lights.jpg